# Big-O Analysis - for-if-do something statement with 3 different time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Here is the example

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  if(IsSignificantData(i))    
      SpecialTreatment(i);
}
```

IsSignificantData(i) is `O(n)`

SpecialTreatment(i)  is `O(n log n)`

1.Is the Big-O result `n^2`? Because it is n*n where the first n is the Big-O for for-loop and anther n is the Big-o for `IsSignificantData`?

2.Is it in a case like this, always use the worst case in the if statement times the for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

With no knowledge about the behavior of `IsSignificantData` (except that it is O(n)), the most that we can say is that the algorithm is O(n² log n). Because in the worst case, `IsSignificantData` returns `true` all the time, and then the algorithm is the same as

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  IsSignificantData(i);
  SpecialTreatment(i);
}
```

O(n log n) is of greater order than O(n), so `IsSignificantData` is basically irrelevant. Then the loop makes it O(n² log n).

The same argument applies if `IsSignificantData` returns `true` randomly half the time, or alternating `true` and `false`, or one `true` out of every thousand times -- in any case where the number of `true`s is proportional to the number of times the function is called, the complexity is O(n² log n).

On the other hand, if `IsSignificantData(i)` returns `true` for just one value (or any fixed number of values) of `i`, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n²). That's because the complexity is the sum of calling `IsSignificantData(i)` n times (which is O(n²)), plus calling `SpecialTreatment` once (or some fixed number of times). And `SpecialTreatment` is O(n log n), which is of lower order than O(n²).

There are other possibilities, too. But all that can be said for sure, with the information given, is that the algorithm is definitely O(n² log n).

Answer (score 0):

1. Big-O of this code is `n*n*n log(n) -> n^3 log(n)`
2. Even though you are using function, your code is actually of the following format:

   ```
   for(1 to n) {
    for ( 1 to n) {
        if (true) {
           for (1 to n) {
              some_log(n) function
           }
         }
       }
   }
   ```

   Having an if statement does not reduce the worst case complexity

Comment: This is not the same complexity as the question's code, which called `SpecialTreatment` at most n times. This snippet does the equivalent of calling `SpecialTreatment` up to n^2 times.